# compile jsx into javascript on-the-fly in node modules

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

my question might be stupid because i am new to react but i'd like to change some node module i've downloaded and i am a bit confused!

i've installed a node module in react.js. inside the node module i get the following files:

```
foo.js
foo.js.flow
bar.js
bar.js.flow
```

the .flow files contain the jsx, the .js files the compiled code which gets used by react.

how can i ensure that when i do a change in the .flow files the change gets automatically compiled into the javascript files?

ps: i am using create-react-app so i got all the tools, i just don't know how to use them in this case.

Comment: If you want to change a module I would suggest rethinking your approach as you've got the wrong tool for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @filth what do you mean with "wrong tool"? i simply like to change some code inside the node_module which should then reflect instantly on the react frontend in the browser....

Comment: Node modules are built as packages to perform a certain task. I would never recommend editing a package just to get it to do what you need. Take some time to rethink your approach to your project and you will find another way.

Comment: but what if i want to extend the node modue and even create a pull request?